# Batik's animation and heavy cpu load

Tags: java, batik

we are using Apache Batik in a project for displaying SVG graphics in a Swing application. When we use the animation tag of SVG, it results in heavy cpu load.

I know there are methods to limit the fps or cpu utilization, but why is Batik taking so much cpu power?

Since release 1.7, it seems that the project is dead. Are there any forks of this project or will it be continued?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations, in particular with vector graphics, just tend to take a lot of CPU. Unless they fully exploit your graphics card acceleration, e.g. by using OpenGL.

As far as I know, Batik so far does all the rendering itself, and cannot offload to your GPU much, so it will use a lot of CPU. (Which on the up side means it will work fine on a server that doesn't have a GPU, allow scripted transcoding, and give guaranteed results.)

Yes, the project seems to lack motivated contributors these days, unfortunately. Just like many other Apache commons projects. But at least it is in a very usable state. But why don't you jump on the project and help out? They have a lot of open bug reports they could use a hand with.

Comment: Now we are limiting the power to a total sum of 20% CPU for our widgets. So each of N widgets can utilize the CPU for 20%/N. I noticed that Batik has a lot of bugs, but we are using it in productive environment. Unfortunately I have no time for contributing the project.